# Click value from auto suggest dropdown in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am developing test automation in selenium using java. my doubt is i am sending value of auto suggest dropdown using send keys
   locater.sendKeys("some values");,
so in dropdown more than one suggestion is showing, when I am using
locater.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
locater.sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
 It selects last option always.
how to click on option which I am sending?

Comment: You can try just press enter key without arrow down.

Comment: If html tag is <select> then you can use `new Select(element).selectByValue("value");`

Comment: no, it is not a select tag, rather it is auto suggest dropdown just like google search

Answer (score 2):

As the Select is [react Select](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/), the below function will work for you.

In your case the id is **32**.

So you can call it like

```
reactSelect("32", "Male"); // reactSelect("32", "male");
```

Function

```
public void reactSelect(String id, String... values) {
    By selectDropArrow = By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control'][span[contains(@id,'react-select-" + id + "')]]/span[@class='Select-arrow-zone']");
    WebElement dropDownArrow = driver.findElement(selectDropArrow);
    dropDownArrow.click();
    if (values != null) {
        for (String value : values) {
            WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='react-select-" + id + "--list']/div[@class='Select-option' and text()='" + value + "']"));
            option.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Full Example

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

/**
 *
 * @author Madhanraj
 */
public class SelTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    public SelTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void start() {
        driver.get("http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/");
        reactSelect("3", "Caramel", "Peppermint");
    }

    public void reactSelect(String id, String... values) {
        By selectDropArrow = By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control'][span[contains(@id,'react-select-" + id + "')]]/span[@class='Select-arrow-zone']");
        WebElement dropDownArrow = driver.findElement(selectDropArrow);
        dropDownArrow.click();
        if (values != null) {
            for (String value : values) {
                WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='react-select-" + id + "--list']/div[@class='Select-option' and text()='" + value + "']"));
                option.click();
            }
        }
    }

    public void quit() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SelTest ss = new SelTest();
        ss.start();
        ss.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't select the last option. The first option should be selected.

If you want to specifically select the option you have given then you can use the code mentioned below:

```
    locator.sendKeys("test match");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement element_move = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[. = 'test match']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element_move).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: hi, i tried the above code but dint get desired result, it is not clicking on any element. To be precise , I want to select gender 'male' , so when I am sending      locator.sendKeys("male");  two suggestions are showing as male and female in order, so when i am using locater.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);   it is selecting female always. if I omit   locater.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN); and using only locater.sendKeys(Keys.Enter); , it is selecting male, that works. but what this will fail too, if my string will be in 2nd or so position.

Comment: Can you give me the HTML of the element. It will help me to fix your code

Comment: <div class="Select-control">    
<span id="react-select-32--value" class="Select-multi-value-wrapper">    
<div class="Select-placeholder">Select Gender</div>    
<div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">   
<input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-32--value" value="" style="width: 19px; box-sizing: content-box;"/>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre;"/>
</div>
</span>
<span class="Select-arrow-zone">


</div>

Comment: I can see "react-select" is been used for creating the dropdown. It is not that straightforward to give the path of the element in the dropdown which is created using react-select.React-Select generates a hidden text field containing the selected value

Comment: exactly, that is the issue. when i select gender then only this elements show up else it does not. how to solve this kind of issue? any idea?

Comment: Yes I have seen this issue earlier. I will need your URL for solving this issue.

Comment: sorry, that is confidential as it is company project and i am not allowed to do so. Can u suggest any way to resolve this issue?